# Sql Select into array - column has seperater

Tags: mysql

I have a column in my DB that has the following data (yeah i know its wrong to have multiple names separated by some random character)

"John Cusack | Thandie Newton | Chiwetel Ejiofor"

I want to be able to separate these people into an array to use later or even just to be able display them like below will help

```
John Cusack
Thandie Newton
Chiwetel Ejiofor
```

any ideas please
thanks in advance

Comment: You mean in pure mySQL? That may be impossible. Are you accessing the data from an application? Then do it in there. Or of course store the data properly, but you already know that....

Comment: not easy to do in mysql. do it client-side, then start planning on normalizing your db so you're not stuck with this again in the future.

Comment: What scripting language are you using?  PHP?  With PHP you can pull the field, explode the string on the pipe | and then trim the white space and put into an array.

Answer (score 0):

As you say, storing delimited lists in an RDBMS *really* is [not a good idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3653574); however, you may be able to use MySQL's string manipulation functions such as [`SUBSTRING_INDEX()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) to obtain your desired results (MySQL doesn't have array types, so I assume you're merely looking to split the data):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_column, '|', 1), -1),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_column, '|', 2), -1),
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(my_column, '|', 3), -1)
FROM   my_table
```

Note that one doesn't actually need to invoke `SUBSTRING_INDEX()` twice for the first and last elements of the list, but I thought it informative to do so in order that the pattern for further elements can be seen more clearly.

If you were so inclined, you *could* build a stored procedure that loops over the string populating a temporary table with each found element—but this is all so far away from "good practice" that it's almost certainly not worth delving into it any further.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this.

```
 select substring_index(substring_index('a|b|c|h', '|',@r:=@r+1),'|',-1) zxz
from (select @r:=0) x,
(select 'x' xx union select 'v' xx union select 'z' xx  union select 'p' xx) z;
```

Result looks like

```
----
|zxz|
-----
|a   |
------
|b   |
------
|c   |
------
|h   |
------
```

locatet here: [Mysql](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html)
and a little modified.

Remember: The "count" of the union statements have to be the same as your delemiter.

Kind Regars